# How to store a session token in database in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I store a session token in database on login? Everytime user login user's session token should get updated and when it is about to expire it should get updated to. I saw in rails guide that using `rails g active_record:session_migration` will create table and that will store all the sessions. Then `YourApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store`. How session will get store in this table?? do i need to write a logic for that? Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full details are on the gem's readme:

https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store

> You may configure the table name, primary key, and data column. For
>   example, at the end of config/application.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.table_name = 'legacy_session_table' 
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.primary_key = 'session_id'
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.data_column_name = 'legacy_session_data'
```

> Note that setting the primary key to the
>   session_id frees you from having a separate id column if you don't
>   want it. However, you must set session.model.id = session.session_id
>   by hand! A before filter on ApplicationController is a good place.
>
> Since the default class is a simple Active Record, you get timestamps
>   for free if you add created_at and updated_at datetime columns to the
>   sessions table, making periodic session expiration a snap.
>
> You may provide your own session class implementation, whether a
>   feature-packed Active Record or a bare-metal high-performance SQL
>   store, by setting
>
> ```
> ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore.session_class = MySessionClass
> ```
>
> You must implement these methods:

```
self.find_by_session_id(session_id)
initialize(hash_of_session_id_and_data, options_hash = {}) 
attr_reader :session_id 
attr_accessor :data 
save 
destroy
```

> The example SqlBypass
>   class is a generic SQL session store. You may use it as a basis for
>   high-performance database-specific stores.

Comment: I will try and update you. Your answer says that I should have Session model which I never had. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer satisfy your problem?